# I have forgotten my iCloud username and password and need to turn Find My iPhone off. What can I do?

Tags: iphone, apple-id, find-my-iphone

I have forgotten my Apple iCloud username and password. I can't remember the email address I used to sign up for the account. I need to turn off Find My iPhone before sending my iPhone in for servicing. My screen won't turn on at all so I don't know what else to do. I am being told that if I don't turn Find My iPhone off I can't get my phone fixed.

Is there any way I can recover my account information and turn off Find My iPhone in this situation?

Comment: Start at https://iforgot.apple.com

Comment: Maybe something obvious, but I have a limited number of email addresses... If it's not a@b.com then it may be cde@b.com, or abcde@xyz.com.  Going through your (probably not huge) list of emails may allow you to do "forgot password" or something like that. Also, did any of your friends do iMessage to your AppleID? Thats probably the same email you used for Activation Lock.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Find My iPhone turned in, then you are signed into iCloud. Go to **Settings** > **iCloud**. At the top it will have a name and iCloud ID. Write down the icloud ID (it may be one of your non-apple email addresses) then click on that and it will ask for the for the password. If you cannot remember it, click the **Forgot Apple ID or Password** link in blue. Enter the iCloud ID you wrote down earlier, then click the **Next** button on the top right of the screen.

Continue to follow the onscreen instructions.

Comment: OP stated her screen is not working